# How to get correct note timings when importing multi-track Midi files?

Tags: import, sound, timing

I have observed when importing midi files with more than one track, the times for every track except for the first one are sped up.

for example,

```
Import[file, "SoundNotes"][[4, -10]]
Import[file, {"SoundNotes", 4}][[-10]]
```

returns

```
SoundNote["F5", {404., 404.569}, "Oboe", SoundVolume -> 0.752941]
SoundNote["F5", {408.062, 408.659}, "Oboe", SoundVolume -> 0.752941]
```

As you can see, by the end of playing this file, the fourth track is over 4 seconds off!

On the other hand, the first track shows no time difference at all between the two import methods:

```
Import[file, "SoundNotes"][[1, -10]]
Import[file, {"SoundNotes", 1}][[-10]]
```

returns

```
SoundNote["F6", {408.062, 408.629}, "Flute", SoundVolume -> 0.752941]
SoundNote["F6", {408.062, 408.629}, "Flute", SoundVolume -> 0.752941]
```

You can definitely hear this offset by the end of the piece, especially if it is a two-track piano midi roll.

How can I properly import the midi without messing up the timestamps for the lower tracks? This bug is present in Mathematica 12.3.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please report this to [Wolfram technical support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).

Answer (score 1):

Since the timing bug is only present in the default mode of importing all tracks at the same time and is absent when importing tracks one-at-a-time, you can resolve the issue by importing each track's notes separately and storing the notes from each track into a list.

```
Sound[Flatten[
  ParallelMap[Import[file, {"SoundNotes", #}] &, 
    Range[Import[file, "TrackCount"]]]
]]
```

Since we are not writing to the file, we can use ParallelMap.

Hopefully this bug can be fixed in the future...